# Nautilus crashes when setting & changing permission on file properties as root 14.10

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus, 14.10

I'm a newbie on ubuntu and I don't know what happened on my os ubuntu 14.10 bc the nautilus file manager always closed when I try to change permission on file properties. I ran it as root in terminal. I wrote `sudo nautilus` in terminal and it was running normally but when I try to change permission on a file, nautilus will suddenly closed and this error was appear in terminal:

`ERROR:nautilus-properties-window.c:1840:schedule_owner_change_timeout: assertion failed: (NAUTILUS_IS_FILE (file))`

Hope anyone can help me to fix this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the permissions from the command line using `sudo chmod *PERMISSIONS* *FILE*`
where *PERMISSIONS* should be:

- `a+x` to give execution permission to all.
- `g+x` to give execution permission to group.
- `u+x` to give execution permission to user.
- You can replace the `+` by a `-` to remove permissions.
- You can change other permissions such as `r` (read) or `w` (write) [i.e. `a+w`]
- You can change one or more permissions at same time (`a+rwx`)

And *FILE* should be the file to change permissions, you can drag and drop from a normal nautilus window to the command line.

Comment: But how do you think? Maybe there's a bug or something? But I really appreciate it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Maybe this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1225563 or this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/467791/nautilus-crashes-when-trying-to-change-permissions-as-root-in-live-session? If my answer solved my problem please mark it as acepted, else wait for a more precise answer (and/or upvote mine).

Comment: Yes I got it, maybe this is a bug and I'll try to send about the bug report.